# Web Scraper Pagination

Tags: pagination, apify

I have created a web scraper where I am trying to fetch the dynamic data which loads in a div after page is load.

Here it is my code and source website url https://www.medizinerkarriere.de/kliniken-sortiert-nach-name.html

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    // jQuery is handy for finding DOM elements and extracting data from them.
    // To use it, make sure to enable the "Inject jQuery" option.
    const $ = context.jQuery;
    var result = [];
    $('#klinikListBox ul').each(function(){        
        var item = {           
            Name: $(this).find('li.klName').text().trim(),
            Ort: $(this).find('li.klOrt').text().trim(),
            Land: $(this).find('li.klLand').text().trim(),            
            Url:""
        };
        result.push(item);    
    });

    // To make this work, make sure the "Use request queue" option is enabled.
    await context.enqueueRequest({ url: 'https://www.medizinerkarriere.de/kliniken-sortiert-nach-name.html' });

    // Return an object with the data extracted from the page.
    // It will be stored to the resulting dataset.
    return result;
}
```

But there are on click pagination and I am not sure how to do it.

I tried all method from this link but it didn't work.

https://docs.apify.com/scraping/web-scraper#bonus-making-your-code-neater

Please help and quick help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the pagination loads dynamically on a single page so enqueuing new pages doesn't make sense. You can get to the next page by simply clicking the page button, it is also a good practice to wait a bit after the click.

```
$('#PGPAGES span').eq(1).click();
await context.waitFor(1000)
```

You can scrape all pages with a simple loop

```
const numberOfPages = 8 // You can scrape this number too
for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
    // Your scraping code, push data to an array and return them in the end
    $('#PGPAGES span').eq(i).click();
    await context.waitFor(1000)
}
```